# wnd.Show(Me) not working in WPF

Tags: wpf, windows, vb.net, .net-4.0

With my old programmes of multiple-windows, I used to use this parameter

```
wnd.Show(Me)
```

This code kept wnd above the first Window. Anyway in WPF it gives error

"Too many arguments for 'Public Sub Show'"

How can I do in WPF having the same advantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the [Window.Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) property in WPF to accomplish this:

```
wnd.Owner = Me
wnd.Show()
```

Comment: It's not the same thing because I'm able to put the Second view down the first when I press "Show desktop" (from Windows taskbar) and reselect Program icon

Answer (score 1):

The function you're trying to use doesn't exist. The [Window.Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) property is what you're looking for.

```
wnd.Owner = Me
wnd.Show()
```

You might also want to be using [Window.ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) if you're trying to keep it on top and modal - "This code kept wnd above the first Window" makes it sound like you're probably going for modal.